# Multiselect column and filter disappears after changing eav_attribute backend_model

Tags: magento2.3

I have multislect attribute which was not saving when product edit,
After updating backend_model column in eav_attribute table with

```
Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend
```

then mutiselect values are saving, but after this attribute missing in grid column and in filtering.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

this is an error on sizee:

```
"options": [
{
    "label": " ",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "label": " ",
    "value": "5489"
},
```

also this

```
"default_value": "",
```

default value, if set, must be a value that you explicited before. So in this case should be:

```
"default_value": " ",
```